# How much memory should be allocated in the following code?

Tags: c, assembly, stack, mips

I knew the stack pointer is kept doubleword aligned,see the code below:

```
main()
{
   printf("The factorial of 10 is %d\n", fact(10));
}
int fact(int n)
{
   if(n<1)
      return (1);
   else
      return (n*fact(n-1));
}
```

The Argument Section has a minimum size of 4 words, plus `$ra` and `$fp`, I think the total size is 24 bytes, while the answer is 32 bytes, why?

Comment: I am not aware that it needs to be double word aligned, especially if it's only calling your own function. You don't need to store `$fp` either, so it should work with 2 words, 8 bytes (which also happens to be double word aligned).

Comment: Why `$fp` needs 2 words ? This register is just 32 bits wide.

Comment: @wow yoo I best stack alignment requirements. But I did not touch MIPS for years now.

Comment: I'm fairly confident this is simply due to alignment.

Comment: Truly caused by the alignment

Comment: At the deepest level the stack contains `fact(10), fact(9), ... fact(0)` = 11 times `fact(n)` call. I don't see how that can be under 40 bytes => 10 times storing return address into stack, and keeping everything else in registers (argument can be adjusted+restored in register, if hand tuned assembly is used, by following C standard the argument should be copied by value, so actually I don't see how the C compiler can get under 80 bytes in this case).

Comment: Maybe i didn't make it clear, the 32 bytes memory is allocated each time the recursive procedure is invoked.